# Create a dynamic nested JSON Java

Tags: java, json, rest, gson

I would like to create a Json out of an array of strings which each look like: 
"id.categoryvalue.subcatvalue.subsubcatvalue.score"
Result should look like this:

```js
{
  "user-id": "u42",
  "categories": [
    {
      "category": "value",
      "subcats": [
        {
          "subcat": "value",
          "subsubcats": [
            {
              "subsubcat": "value",
              "score": 47
            }  
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't want to duplicate a value in the same category, what would be an effective way to solve it? Thanks!

Comment: What is the input?

Comment: "id.categoryvalue.subcatvalue.subsubcatvalue.score"

Comment: No we need your "array of strings"

Comment: For example: "id31.english.B1.Animals.11", "id21.english.B2.Insects.24" etc

Comment: please add the relevant information to the question.

Comment: which language do you need? Java !== Javascript

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the format of input remains constant, you can do the following:

- `Tokenize` the input string by splitting it with `.`
- Declare/initialise the structures (e.g. `Map` and set appropriate values)
- Convert resultant object to `String` using any `JSON` parser

Below example demonstrates it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Map<String, Object> result = convertToMap("id.categoryvalue.subcatvalue.subsubcatvalue.score");
    System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(result));
}

public static Map<String, Object> convertToMap(String input){
    Map<String, Object> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    String[] tokens = input.split("\\.");

    if(tokens.length < 5){
        //Invalid string, return
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Insufficient tokens");
    }

    //Add user id
    result.put("user-id", tokens[0]);

    //Add category
    Map<String, Object> category = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    category.put("category", tokens[1]);

    //Add sub category
    Map<String, Object> subCategory = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    subCategory.put("subcat", tokens[2]);

    //Add nested category
    Map<String, Object> nestedSubCategory = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    nestedSubCategory.put("subsubcat", tokens[3]);
    nestedSubCategory.put("score", Integer.parseInt(tokens[4]));

    subCategory.put("subcats", Arrays.asList(new Map[] {nestedSubCategory}));
    category.put("subcats", Arrays.asList(new Map[] {subCategory}));
    result.put("categories", Arrays.asList(new Map[] {category}));

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Gson you can generate the JSON using either the object model way or the streaming way. The first one requires the whole object to be built before generating the JSON either in a strongly typed manner (see below) or a weakly typed one (like what [Darshan Mehta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1120793/darshan-mehta) suggested -- he used a weak objects based on Java maps).

### Object model approach

Decompose the given data into several data bag classes, construct the objects of these classes, an just invoke Gson:

```java
public final class ObjectModelDemo {

    private ObjectModelDemo() {
    }

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        final String[] tokens = "id31.english.B1.Animals.11".split("\\.");
        if ( tokens.length != 5 ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not 5 tokens in " + "id31.english.B1.Animals.11");
        }
        final String userId = tokens[0];
        final String category = tokens[1];
        final String subcategory = tokens[2];
        final String subsubcategory = tokens[3];
        final int score = parseInt(tokens[4]);
        final User user = new User(
                userId,
                singletonList(new Category(
                        category,
                        singletonList(new Subcategory(
                                subcategory,
                                singletonList(new Subsubcategory(subsubcategory, score))
                        ))
                ))
        );
        final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        out.println(gson.toJson(user));
    }

    private static final class User {

        @SerializedName("user-id")
        private final String userId;

        @SerializedName("categories")
        private final List<Category> categories;

        private User(final String userId, final List<Category> categories) {
            this.userId = userId;
            this.categories = categories;
        }

    }

    private static final class Category {

        @SerializedName("category")
        private final String category;

        @SerializedName("subcats")
        private final List<Subcategory> subcategories;

        private Category(final String category, final List<Subcategory> subcategories) {
            this.category = category;
            this.subcategories = subcategories;
        }

    }

    private static final class Subcategory {

        @SerializedName("subcat")
        private final String subcategory;

        @SerializedName("subsubcats")
        private final List<Subsubcategory> subsubcategories;

        private Subcategory(final String subcategory, final List<Subsubcategory> subsubcategories) {
            this.subcategory = subcategory;
            this.subsubcategories = subsubcategories;
        }

    }

    private static final class Subsubcategory {

        @SerializedName("subsubcat")
        private final String subsubcategory;

        @SerializedName("score")
        private final int score;

        private Subsubcategory(final String subsubcategory, final int score) {
            this.subsubcategory = subsubcategory;
            this.score = score;
        }

    }

}
```

Such data bags are called DTOs ([data-transfer objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)) and are designed to map between Java objects and their respective JSON representation. This gives you very strong compile-time control support by the Java compiler. Disadvantage of this approach is that you must collect all the data before any JSON generation begins (usually this is very crucial for memory-sensitive applications). However, for your case, this can be much and much easier, and probably the most easy one.

The output:

> {"user-id":"id31","categories":[{"category":"english","subcats":[{"subcat":"B1","subsubcats":[{"subsubcat":"Animals","score":11}]}]}]}

### Streaming approach

An alternative approach based on intermediate writing a JSON to a destination. This approach is a data-pushing approach that is more complex, however it is more efficient from the memory consumption point of view (even more, you can easily generate infinite JSONs using this method, but I doubt you'll ever have such a situation :) ).

```java
    public static void main(final String... args)
            throws IOException {
        final String[] tokens = "id21.english.B2.Insects.24".split("\\.");
        if ( tokens.length != 5 ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not 5 tokens in " + "id21.english.B2.Insects.24");
        }
        final String userId = tokens[0];
        final String category = tokens[1];
        final String subcategory = tokens[2];
        final String subsubcategory = tokens[3];
        final int score = parseInt(tokens[4]);
        final JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out));
        writeUser(jsonWriter, userId, category, subcategory, subsubcategory, score);
        jsonWriter.flush();
        // do not invoke jsonWriter.close() -- let the caller decide what to do
    }

    private static void writeUser(final JsonWriter jsonWriter, final String userId, final String category, final String subcategory,
            final String subsubcategory, final int score)
            throws IOException {
        jsonWriter.beginObject();
        jsonWriter.name("user-id");
        jsonWriter.value(userId);
        jsonWriter.name("categories");
        writeCategories(jsonWriter, category, subcategory, subsubcategory, score);
        jsonWriter.endObject();
    }

    private static void writeCategories(final JsonWriter jsonWriter, final String category, final String subcategory, final String subsubcategory,
            final int score)
            throws IOException {
        jsonWriter.beginArray();
        jsonWriter.beginObject();
        jsonWriter.name("category");
        jsonWriter.value(category);
        jsonWriter.name("subcats");
        writeSubcategories(jsonWriter, subcategory, subsubcategory, score);
        jsonWriter.endObject();
        jsonWriter.endArray();
    }

    private static void writeSubcategories(final JsonWriter jsonWriter, final String subcategory, final String subsubcategory, final int score)
            throws IOException {
        jsonWriter.beginArray();
        jsonWriter.beginObject();
        jsonWriter.name("subcat");
        jsonWriter.value(subcategory);
        jsonWriter.name("subsubcats");
        writeSubsubcategories(jsonWriter, subsubcategory, score);
        jsonWriter.endObject();
        jsonWriter.endArray();
    }

    private static void writeSubsubcategories(final JsonWriter jsonWriter, final String subsubcategory, final int score)
            throws IOException {
        jsonWriter.beginArray();
        jsonWriter.beginObject();
        jsonWriter.name("subsubcat");
        jsonWriter.value(subsubcategory);
        jsonWriter.name("score");
        jsonWriter.value(score);
        jsonWriter.endObject();
        jsonWriter.endArray();
    }

}
```

Pay attention on how data is written to the output stream: once you have enough known data, you can easily flush it to the output stream. Yep, this is a more hard-to-write approach, but this is an alternative.

The output:

> {"user-id":"id21","categories":[{"category":"english","subcats":[{"subcat":"B2","subsubcats":[{"subsubcat":"Insects","score":24}]}]}]}